# How to make sure the exist of "email.FeedParser" module

Tags: python

After installing gspread and oauth2client.

When I execute Python program for sending data to Google Spread Sheet, the console said "Import Error ：no module named email.FeedParser". like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Downloads/gspread2.py", line 6, in <module>
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 25, in <module>
from oauth2client import client
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 39, in <module>
from oauth2client import transport
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 17, in <module>
import httplib2
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
import email.FeedParser
ImportError: No module named 'email.FeedParser'
```

mycode

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
import gspread
import email
email.feedparser
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
       'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('home/pi/Downloads/RasPi2Spread-20f37a9db352.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open('gspreadサンプル').sheet1

wks.update_acell('A1', 'Hello World!')
print(wks.acell('A1'))
```

and then, though I tried finding the exist of the module, I didn't know how to find it. Also, I don't know how to install the library including the module.

Please tell me the way to solve this trouble.

Comment: I imported **email.FeedParser** successfully in **both in python 2.7.15** but try **email.feedparser in python 3.7.2**

Answer (score 0):

To know the list of python packages installed you can try `pip freeze` in `CMD`.

For saving in text file `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in `CMD`

To install any python package use `pip install package-name`

Your answer:

```
    import email
    email.feedparser
```